# Не отображается ссылка при создании бургер меню кнопки

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

При создании бургер меню кнопки, ссылка распространяется лишь на линии burger_menu__lines, которые я расположил внутри burger_menu__button, я хочу чтобы ссылка распространялось на весь баттон

```html
<div class="burger_menu">
  <a href="" class="burger_menu__button>">
    <span class="burger_menu__lines"></span>
  </a>
</div>
<style>
  .burger_menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    z-index: 30;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: green;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
  }
  
  .burger_menu__lines,
  .burger_menu__lines::before,
  .burger_menu__lines::after {
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 4px;
    background-color: #EBC181;
  }
  
  .burger_menu__lines {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
  }
  
  .burger_menu__lines::before {
    content: '';
    top: -12px;
  }
  
  .burger_menu__lines::after {
    content: '';
    top: 12px;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Потому что тег ```a``` - это строчный элемент, добавьте для этого тега, например,  ```display:flex```

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте ссылке: display: block; ширину и высоту на всю площадь родительского элемента.

```
.burger_menu__button {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```css
    .burger_menu {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 10px;
        z-index: 30;
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        background-color: green;
        border: 2px solid #ccc;
      }
      .burger_menu__lines,
      .burger_menu__lines::before,
      .burger_menu__lines::after{
        position: absolute;
        width: 30px;
        height: 4px;
        background-color: #EBC181;
      }
      .burger_menu__lines {
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
      }
    
      .burger_menu__lines::before{
        content: '';
        top: -12px;
      }
      .burger_menu__lines::after{
        content: '';
        top: 12px;
      }


      .burger_menu__button {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
```

```html
  <div class="burger_menu">
       <a href="" class="burger_menu__button">
          <span class="burger_menu__lines"></span>
       </a>
    </div>
```